# Magento 2: New Customers not showing in backend

Tags: magento2, customer, cron, reindex

I cannot see new customers in my M2 backend customers list and I figure out it's happening because my "Customer Grid" is not reindexed(Reindex required), Here is manual method to re-index CLI: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` but how to make reindex automatically? like cronjob?

Comment: by doing reindex it's Skipping customer_grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct. In Magento 2, the indexing process is triggerred by the cron and cannot be triggered manually anymore.

To setup your cron I suggest you follow the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: Can I use cPanel cron job? like this
`$ php-cli /home/myuser/public_html/bin/magento       indexer:reindex`

Comment: @RiyasMuhammed I guess so yes. Give it a try

Comment: Ok for now I have set `php bin/magento cron:run` let see how its work!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem after a migration from 1.9.x to 2.1.x

• `php bin/magento cron:run`

• `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

• Flush Magento cache

Make sure you setup your crons correctly as @Raphael suggested